# How can I find the source of rust in my water supply

Tags: faucet, pipe, safety, rust, rental

I live in the Seattle area, in a rental house that was built in 1956.

Sometimes when I open faucets (especially after trip), brown water comes out from the faucet for a few seconds before running clear.

I use filtered water for drinking and cooking, but the dishwasher, showers, bathroom sinks, etc. are not filtered, of course.

How do I go about figuring out the issue, and what do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Possible sediment from the water itself or the water is picking up loose sediment from the pipes.  Do you know the water source, well or city?

Comment: Whole house filter. Replace all the pipes. Water softer. Flush HW tank. Not a safety issue. - Or just know that after a trip that you have to run the water. In a rental, I'd be surprised if they did any of that for you. Unless you can go to them and say my dishes are spotty, my laundry is turning brown, and when I water the lawn the siding on the house turns red.

Comment: You'll have to determine what supply components are iron. You could have galvanized pipe somewhere in the house, or it could be the line from the street. The question is too broad until you narrow down the cause, though.

Comment: Probably CWI - clear water iron - dissolved in the water source. Get the water running clear, fill a large white or clear container, let it sit and/or stir/shake it to oxygenate the water. If rust forms, it's CWI - if black sandy stuff forms, it's manganese. You might have both. You can get that on a supply that hasn't got an inch of iron piping, if it's in the water source. Guess how I know... confirmation would be a water test, but that costs money.

Answer (score 1):

Divide and conquer. Determine if the rust is present via the tap closest to where the water comes in (in piping feet). If it is, the rust is upstream of that, at the meter or the water mains or in the water supply.

If it isn't, go through other taps determining where you and don't set rust, and find the branch of the piping where everything on it has rust and nothing not on it does.